# Synthesizer sound design or music production questions

Tags: discussion, support

If I don't have a problem, may I still ask a question to review my sounds? I use a Mackie ProFx16 mixer with Roland 808 and Roland 909. I only use software synths. I owned the Juno 60, 106, the Nord Modular, Kord MS20 etc but software synths sound at least as good and are easier to program. Now if I want a general "request for comment" about sounds I did at soundcloud and not really trying to solve a specific problem, the question is subjective how you like the sound.

Would such a question be a good fit for the site or is it too subjective? I suppose I could phrase it as a hardware or software recommendation question what to buy to improve my sound or what to learn.

Comment: I once proposed a new site on Area51 called "Master Class" which would be for performance reviews. But I can't find any evidence of that proposal. We do have *Code Review* but no review sites for "Art" per se.

Answer (score 4):

That would be off topic here as subjective and opinion based, as you guessed.

Software and hardware recommendation questions are also off topic here (but we do have Stack Exchange sites for both)

The Sound Design site is the closest to what you want, I think, although questions like this are more focused towards "I want this type of sound, how can I generate it?"